# How to combine lineplot and 3dplot in mathematica having same axes?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to merge the 2dline plot to 3dplot. any help will be appreciated.[image: 2dline plot]

```
j1 = Transpose[{i8, i2}];
k1 = ListLinePlot[j1, AxesLabel -> {"x", "z"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotRange -> {{500, 1500}, {0, 160}}, 
AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004], 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold},
ImageSize -> Large];

s1 = Transpose[{p8, p1, p2}];
h2 = ListPointPlot3D[s1, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
PlotStyle -> Green, 
PlotRange -> {{500, 1500}, {0., 0.5}, {0, 160}}, 
AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004], 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold},
ImageSize -> Large];

Show[h2, k1]
```

[image: code for 3d plot]

Comment: A 2D and 3D plot cannot be combined. Why not modify `j1` to add whatever `y` value it corresponds to the `s1` data. Use a wrapper to style the augmented `j1` values with a different color.

Answer (score 1):

```
j1 = Table[{i, Sin[2^2 + i]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.05}];

k1 = ListLinePlot[j1]
```

[image]

Extract the line and convert it to 3D

```
y0 = 2;

line = Cases[k1, Line[pts_] :> Line[{#[[1]], y0, #[[2]]} & /@ pts], 
    Infinity][[1]];

s1 = Table[{i, j, Sin[j^2 + i]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];
```

Combine the line with the `ListPointPlot3D`

```
Show[
 ListPointPlot3D[s1],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, line}]]
```

[image]

Clear["Global`*"]

**EDIT:** Using your data

```
file1 = Import["/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/i1.xlsx"];

j1 = Sort@file1[[1, All, {8, 2}]];

file2 = Import[
   "/Users/roberthanlon/Downloads/p1.ifs0_positive_oldc_chargecode"];

s1 = file2[[All, {8, 1, 2}]];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[s1, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
   PlotStyle -> Green,
   PlotRange -> {{500, 1500}, {0., 0.5}, {0, 160}},
   AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.004],
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 16, FontFamily -> "Times", Black, Bold},
   ImageSize -> Medium],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Thick, Line[{#[[1]], y0, #[[2]]} & /@ j1]}]],
 {{y0, 0}, 0, 0.5, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Bob. But both of my tables are totally different columns, though they have the same scale I can't repeat i in the second loop. Trying to get it.

Comment: We cannot tell you exactly what to do since you did not provide us with the data or an appropriate subset of the data.

Comment: I have no idea how to attach in mathematica. The files are on this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1o2a6O2o6ouCJia6zK4mUkSKtBWFNZtIu?usp=sharing . p1 file 1,8 and 2nd columns are chosen and i1 file 2 and 8 columns are chosen. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Thank you very much Bob Hanlon,from the bottom of my heart. You resolved my big headache.